# Layered paper-dropdown-menu in paper-dialog

Tags: polymer, material-design, web-component, paper-elements

I'm prototyping an app which opens few layers of dialogs as user gets into configuration options. I wanted to use *paper-dropdown-menu* inside one of the dialogs. It displays completely within its parent causing scrollbars to appear. I want it to appear at the same spot but overflowing parent.

You can see how it looks on: [paper-dropdown-menu demo page](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown-menu/demo.html). Just click toggle overlay and open the menu that pops up in the center.

I tried multiple positioning variants, nothing seems to work.

Is there a way that I can't figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the layered attribute should straighten things out. there is a bit about how to use it on the polymer blog. https://blog.polymer-project.org/releases/2014/11/12/release-0.5.1/ just look for the section on breaking child structure.

edit: looking back over the demo you linked. they use the layered attribute on the dropdown in the overlay. it looks like this might be a bug with core-overlay i have seen some strange behavior with it lately. but the layered attribute is what we are supposed to use in situations like this.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This info is not easy to find.
_adding blog to feedly_

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all? https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dialog/issues/50#issuecomment-76563028

I ran into a problem putting a layered `<paper-dropdown-menu>` inside a layered `<paper-dialog>` because they both used a separate `<core-overlay-layer>` element that had the same z-index.  I did a little workaround to renumber their z-indexes when a new overlay is added.

```
   domReady: function () {
        jQuery("body").on('core-overlay-open', function(e) {
            var zi = 1000;
            jQuery("core-overlay-layer").each(function (ei, elem) {
                elem.style.zIndex = zi--;
            });
        });
    },
```